# Flask - How can I paginate data coming in from an API? (No database)

Tags: python, api, flask

So, I want to be able to paginate data that is coming in from an API, but I am not sure how to. I have looked at pagination with Flask and almost everyone is using SQLAlchemy and a Database to paginate, so I am kind of stuck right now. I had tried everything but I havent been lucky, so I hope you guys can help me with this matter. Thanks a lo.

This is the code that gets me the data from the API:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import requests
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

api = '12589634-45tg33ww8633f1cdfrre3345'
url = 'https://pixabay.com/api/'

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def homePage():

    per_page = 18
    page = request.args.get('page', 0, type=int)
    query = request.args.get('s', 'cats')
    
    payload = {'key': api, 'q': query, 'per_page': per_page, 'page': page}
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    data = response.json()
    results = data.get('hits')
    images = results

    return render_template('home_page.html', images=images)

Here is my template:

<pre>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
        {% for image in images %}
        <div class="column is-full-mobile is-half-tablet is-one-third-desktop">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <figure class="image is-4by3">
                        <img src="{{image.webformatURL}}" alt="{{image.tags}}">
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <figure class="image is-48x48">
                                {% if image.userImageURL %}
                                <img src="{{image.userImageURL}}" alt="{{image.user}}">
                                {% else %}
                                <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/avatar/avatar.png')}}" alt="no user image">
                                {% endif %}
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-content">
                            <p class="title is-5">Uploaded by</p>
                            <p class="subtitle is-6">@{{image.user}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p class="title is-6">Likes: {{image.likes}}</p>
                        <p class="title is-6">Type: {{image.type}}</p>
                        <p class="title is-6">Views: {{image.views}}</p>
                        <a href="{{image.largeImageURL}}" class="button is-dark is-fullwidth" target="_blank"
                            rel="noopener nofollow">View
                            full</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <nav class="pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
        <a class="pagination-previous" title="This is the first page" disabled>Previous</a>
        <a class="pagination-next">Next page</a>
        <ul class="pagination-list">
            <li>
                <a class="pagination-link is-current" aria-label="Page 1" aria-current="page">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="pagination-link" aria-label="Goto page 2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="pagination-link" aria-label="Goto page 3">3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock content %}
</pre>
```

Comment: One option is to have a default number of images per page, and then return the images as a list of lists with length equals to the number of images per page. Then you can have a counter to navigate through the results.

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can make a custom paginator. A simple example to it.

```
[...]
ques =   images # the images variable you are passing.

page_num = request.args.get("page_num")
no_of_ques = request.args.get("no_of_ques")
# some error handling
try:
    no_of_ques = int(no_of_ques)
except:
    no_of_ques = 10
    
if page_num == None:
    page_num = 0

try: 
    page_num = int(page_num) 
except:
    abort(404) 
# logic to get the last page
last = math.ceil(len(ques)/no_of_ques) - 1
# logic to get images on a page
ques1 = ques[page_num*no_of_ques:(page_num+1)*no_of_ques] # paginatted
# making the links for a  tagsg
if last == 0:
    next = "#"
    prev = "#"
elif page_num == 0:
    next = f"/?page_num={page_num+1}"
    prev = "#"
elif page_num == last:
    next = "#"
    prev = f"/?page_num={page_num-1}"
else:
    next = f"/?page_num={page_num+1}"
    prev = f"/?page_num={page_num-1}"

if (page_num > last  or not str(page_num).isnumeric(): 
    abort(404) 
return render_template("html_file.html",images=ques1,next=next,prev=prev)

# ques1 has the number of images on  a page.
```

in html make two a tag

```
<a   class="btn btn-primary" src="{{prev}}" >&larr; prev</a>
<a  class="btn btn-primary" src={{next}} >Next →</a>
```

This might not be the best solution but will do the work.